# How can I get the plot label from the name of the plotted list?

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica, mathematica-8

I have a list of data called `DataList`. I can plot the data using `ListPlot` and name that plot after the input list like this:

> `ListPlot[DataList, PlotLabel -> ToString[HoldForm[DataList]]]`

This works and I get the plot just like I want to. But I have a lot of data lists, so I write a function for this purpose, using the following:

> `plot[input_] := ListPlot[input, PlotLabel -> ToString[HoldForm[input]]]`

However, when I input a list now, the “PlotLabel” will not reflect the name of the list I put in, but rather the content of that list.

Is there any way to extract the name of the list/expression before the function evaluates it?

Any other ideas to circumvent the problem?

I am very grateful for any tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DataList = {1, 2, 5, 4, 3, 7};
SetAttributes[plot, HoldFirst];
plot[input_] := ListPlot[input, PlotLabel -> ToString[Unevaluated[input]]];
plot[DataList]

...PlotWithPlotLabel  DataList  snipped...
```

Comment: For some reason, it won't work when I map the "plot"-function on several data lists, like this:
   Map[plot,{DataList01,DataList02,...}]

But if I also give plot the "Listable" attribute, I can at least do this:
   plot[{DataList01,DataList02,...}]

Comment: @Stian That's because `Map` doesn't hold its second argument, so e.g. `DataList01` will evaluate.  You can prevent this with `Map[plot, Unevaluated @ {DataList01,DataList02,...}]`.  I encourage you to ask any addition question on the dedicated [Mathematica.SE] site.

Comment: Bill, +1, and I encourage you also to join us on [Mathematica.SE].